# Oracle/SQL - Need help optimizing this union/group/count query

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, union

I'm trying to optimize this query however possible.  In my test tables this does exactly what I want it too, but on the live tables this takes a VERY long time to run.

```
select   THING_, 
            count(case STATUS_ when '_Good_' then 1 end) as GOOD, 
            count(case STATUS_ when '_Bad_' then 1 end) as BAD,
            count(case STATUS_ when '_Bad_' then 1 end) / count(case STATUS_ when '_Good_' then 1 end) * 100 as FAIL_PERCENT
    from    
                (
                select      THING_,
                            STATUS_,
                    from    <good table>
                    where   TIMESTAMP_ > (sysdate - 1) and
                            STATUS_ = '_Good_' and
                            upper(THING_) like '%TEST%'

                UNION ALL           

                select      THING_,
                            STATUS_,
                    from    <bad table>
                    where   TIMESTAMP_ > (sysdate - 1) and
                            STATUS_ = '_Bad_' and
                            THING_THING_ like '%TEST%'
                ) u
    group by THING_
```

I think by looking at the query it should be self explanatory what I want to do, but if not or if additional info is needed please let me know and I will post some sample tables.

Thanks!

Comment: Are `good table` and `bad table` real tables and not e. g. views, nested queries etc.?

Comment: Generate the execution plans for the test and production environments

Comment: How big are the tables and what is a "VERY long time". If you have 10 million rows matching the criteria, then there is a limit to how fast it can go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1)  Looking at the execution plan should always be your first step in diagnosing SQL performance issues

(2)  A possible problem with the query as written is that, because SYSDATE is a function that is not evaluated until execution time (i.e. after the execution plan is determined), the optimizer cannot make use of histograms on the timestamp column to evaluate the utility of an index.  I have seen that lead to bad optimizer decisions.  If you can work out a way to calculate the date first then feed it into the query as a bind or a literal, that may help, although this is really just a guess.

(3)  Maybe a better overall way to structure the query would be as a join (possibly full outer join) between aggregate queries on each of the tables.

```
SELECT COALESCE(g.thing_,b.thing_), COALESCE(good_count,0), COALESCE(bad_count,0)
  FROM (SELECT thing_,count(*) good_count from good_table WHERE ... GROUP BY thing_) g
       FULL OUTER JOIN
       (SELECT thing_,count(*) bad_count from bad_table WHERE ... GROUP BY thing_) b
       ON b.thing_ = g.thing_
```

(Have to say, it seems kind of weird that you have two separate tables when you also have a status column to indicate "good" or "bad".  But maybe I am overinterpreting.)

Answer (score 2):

Create composite indexes on `(STATUS_, TIMESTAMP_)` in both tables.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried analytical function to use? It might decrease some time execution. Here you are an example:

```
select distinct col1, col2, col3
(Select col1,
       count(col2) over (partition by col1) col2,
       count(col3) over (partition by col1) col3
from table
)
```

Its something like that.